# Understanding #pragma acc kernels

Tags: c, optimization, openacc

I'm trying to optimize nbody algorithm and when I add #pragma acc kernels in the loop, I don't understand what are the following comment

```
#pragma acc kernels
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    real fx, fy, fz;
    fx = fy = fz = 0;

    real iPosx = in[i].x;
    real iPosy = in[i].y;
    real iPosz = in[i].z;

    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {   
      real rx, ry, rz;

      rx = in[j].x - iPosx;
      ry = in[j].y - iPosy;
      rz = in[j].z - iPosz;

      real distSqr = rx*rx+ry*ry+rz*rz;
      distSqr += SOFTENING_SQUARED;

      real s = in[j].w / POW(distSqr,1.5);

      real3 ff;
      ff.x = rx * s;
      ff.y = ry * s;
      ff.z = rz * s;

      fx += ff.x;
      fy += ff.y;
      fz += ff.z;
    }

    force[i].x = fx;
    force[i].y = fy;
    force[i].z = fz;
  }
```

[image: output]

What means "generating implicit reduction(+:fx)

"generating implicit reduction(+:fy)

"generating implicit reduction(+:fz)"?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to parallelize the inner "j" loop, the three variables fx, fy, and fz must be in a sum reduction. The compiler has automatically detected this an therefor implicitly added the reduction for you.  It's the same as if you had explicitly declared them, for example:

```
#pragma acc loop reduction(+:fx,fy,fz)
 for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
{   
  real rx, ry, rz;
```